# get value from 2 bootstrap button groups

Tags: jquery, html, button, bootstrap-4

I am using two bootstrap button groups using bootstrap. I am trying to get the value separately from these button groups using jquery. I tried a few things but nothing seem to work.

```
div class="btn-group" id="blood_button">
            <button type="button" value="ABO" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm active" >All</button>
            <button type="button" value="A" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >A</button>
            <button type="button" value="B" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">B</button>
            <button type="button" value="O" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >O</button>
            <button type="button" value="AB" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">AB</button>
            <button type="button" value="U" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >None</button>
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both">
        <div class="btn-group" id="bmi_button">
            <button type="button" value="0" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm active" >All</button>
            <button type="button" value="1" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">18.5</button>
            <button type="button" value="2" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >18.5-25</button>
            <button type="button" value="3" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">25-30</button>
            <button type="button" value="4" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">30-35</button>
            <button type="button" value="5" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">35-50</button>
            <button type="button" value="6" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">50+</button>
            <button type="button" value="NR" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">None</button>
        </div>
```

I tried---

```
$("#bmi_button").on('click',function(){
    console.log($('#bmi_button > button').val());
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find all the buttons and loop through them to get their values. Look at the sample code below and you might get an idea.

```js
$('#bmi_button').click(function(){
    var allBtns = $('#bmi_group').find('button');
    allBtns.each(function(index, btn){
        console.log('Bmi: ', $(btn).val());
    })
})
$('#blood_group_button').click(function(){
    var allBtns = $('#blood_group').find('button');
    allBtns.each(function(index, btn){
        console.log('Blood Group: ', $(btn).val());
    })
})

var bmi_selected = 0,
    blood_group = '';
$('#bmi_group').click(function(e){
  bmi_selected = e.target.value;
  console.log(e.target.value);
})

$('#blood_group').click(function(e){
  bmi_selected = e.target.value;
  console.log(e.target.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" id="blood_group">
    <button type="button" value="ABO" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm active" >All</button>
    <button type="button" value="A" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >A</button>
    <button type="button" value="B" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">B</button>
    <button type="button" value="O" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >O</button>
    <button type="button" value="AB" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">AB</button>
    <button type="button" value="U" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >None</button>
</div>
<br style="clear:both">
<div class="btn-group" id="bmi_group">
    <button type="button" value="0" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm active" >All</button>
    <button type="button" value="1" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">18.5</button>
    <button type="button" value="2" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >18.5-25</button>
    <button type="button" value="3" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">25-30</button>
    <button type="button" value="4" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">30-35</button>
    <button type="button" value="5" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">35-50</button>
    <button type="button" value="6" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">50+</button>
    <button type="button" value="NR" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">None</button>
</div>
        
<button id="bmi_button">get bmi</button>
<button id="blood_group_button"> get bloog groups</button>
```

Comment: I just need the value of the selected button separately from each button groups. In the bmi group if I click 18.5 I want to store 1 in a separate variable similarly for blood group

Comment: Each time you click on a button it will replacing the old value or both the values will be stored?

Answer (score 1):

you almost had it, you just needed to specify the click on the buttons and not the container

```js
$(function() {
  $("#blood_button > button").on("click", function() {
    alert(this.value);
  });

  $("#bmi_button > button").on("click", function() {
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" id="blood_button">
  <button type="button" value="ABO" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm active">All</button>
  <button type="button" value="A" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">A</button>
  <button type="button" value="B" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">B</button>
  <button type="button" value="O" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">O</button>
  <button type="button" value="AB" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">AB</button>
  <button type="button" value="U" name="blood" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">None</button>
</div>
<br style="clear:both">
<div class="btn-group" id="bmi_button">
  <button type="button" value="0" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm active">All</button>
  <button type="button" value="1" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">18.5</button>
  <button type="button" value="2" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">18.5-25</button>
  <button type="button" value="3" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">25-30</button>
  <button type="button" value="4" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">30-35</button>
  <button type="button" value="5" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">35-50</button>
  <button type="button" value="6" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">50+</button>
  <button type="button" value="NR" name="bmi" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">None</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kuhu Gupta I don't know if you typed in your code wrongly for the JQuery part but please try the following:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#bmi_button").click(function(){
           alert("BMI_Button was clicked");
        });

       $("#blood_button").click(function(){
            alert("Blood Button was clicked");
       });        
   });
```

You are missing semi-colons after each event and it also helps to know when the page is ready by using the ready event. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: how do i get the value? It does not seem to work when I try to do alert($(this).val())

Comment: This in practice doesn't make much sense to do with buttons, because why would you use a group of buttons that could individually be wired to do something, to then have another button to get the value of which button was pressed? I would use a group of radio buttons, and then use the following code in order to get the value of which one was pressed: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/get-radio-button-value-using-jquery.html